How to Implement a Phone Number Input with Country Code Selector in Next.js Using Material-UI or Similar UI Libraries?
I'm working on a login component for a React project, and I'm trying to implement a phone number input field similar to the one in the attached screenshot. The UI consists of a simple input field where users can enter their phone number after selecting their country code, followed by a "Sign In" button.
I've attached a screenshot of the UI component and my code.

import { Box, Button, Typography, Container } from "@mui/material";
import { useState } from "react";
import styles from "./styles.module.css";

const GoogleIcon = () => (
  <svg
    className={styles.googleIcon}
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    viewBox="0 0 48 48"
  >
    <title>Google Icon</title>
    <path
      fill="#4285F4"
      d="M24 9.5c3.26 0 6.15 1.26 8.24 3.32l6.12-6.12C34.2 3.04 29.41 1 24 1 14.97 1 7.49 6.48 4.46 14.02l7.6 5.9C14.43 13.1 18.85 9.5 24 9.5z"
    />
    <path
      fill="#34A853"
      d="M47.52 24.53c0-1.66-.15-3.2-.42-4.73H24v9.18h13.32c-.57 2.85-2.06 5.3-4.34 6.93l6.8 5.29c3.98-3.67 6.74-9.07 6.74-15.67z"
    />
    <path
      fill="#FBBC05"
      d="M11.77 28.18c-.78-2.28-.78-4.74 0-7.02L4.17 15.26C1.51 20.29 1.51 27.71 4.17 32.74l7.6-5.9z"
    />
    <path
      fill="#EA4335"
      d="M24 47c5.41 0 10.2-1.86 13.64-5.04l-6.8-5.29c-1.88 1.26-4.24 2.01-6.84 2.01-5.15 0-9.57-3.6-11.13-8.52l-7.6 5.9C7.49 41.52 14.97 47 24 47z"
    />
    <path fill="none" d="M1 1h46v46H1z" />
  </svg>
);

const LoginForm: React.FC = () => {
  const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState("");
  const [countryCode, setCountryCode] = useState("IN");

  const handlePhoneNumberChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setPhoneNumber(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleCountryCodeChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
    setCountryCode(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(`Country Code: ${countryCode}, Phone Number: ${phoneNumber}`);
  };

  return (
    <Container maxWidth="xs" className={styles.container}>
      <Box className={styles.box}>
        <Typography variant="h5" className={styles.title}>
          Login
        </Typography>
        <Typography variant="body2" className={styles.subtitle}>
          to your XXX
        </Typography>

        <Button variant="contained" className={styles.googleButton}>
          <GoogleIcon />
          Continue with Google
        </Button>

        <div className={styles.separatorContainer}>
          <hr className={styles.separatorLine} />
          <Typography variant="body2" className={styles.orText}>
            or sign in with Phone No.
          </Typography>
          <hr className={styles.separatorLine} />
        </div>

        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <Typography variant="body2" className={styles.inputLabel}>
            Phone Number
          </Typography>

          <Box className={styles.inputContainer}>
            <select
              className={styles.countryCode}
              value={countryCode}
              onChange={handleCountryCodeChange}
            >
              <option value="IN">IN +91</option>
              <option value="US">US +1</option>
              {/* Add more country codes as needed */}
            </select>

            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Enter Your Mobile Number"
              className={styles.phoneNumber}
              value={phoneNumber}
              onChange={handlePhoneNumberChange}
              required
              aria-label="Phone Number"
            />
          </Box>

          <Button
            variant="contained"
            fullWidth
            className={styles.signInButton}
            type="submit"
          >
            Sign In
          </Button>
        </form>
      </Box>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default LoginForm;


Additionally, here’s the CSS I’m using:
.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.box {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 400px;
}

.title {
    font: var(--font-open_sans);
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #333;
    text-align: left;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.subtitle {
    font: var(--font-open_sans);
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #888;
    text-align: left;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
}

.googleButton {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 0;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #000000;
    border: 2px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 70px;
    font: var(--font-open_sans);
    text-transform: none;
    font-weight: 600;
    box-shadow: none;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
}

.googleButton:hover {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.googleIcon {
    margin-right: 8px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
}

.separatorContainer {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.separatorLine {
    flex-grow: 1;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    border: none;
}

.orText {
    color: #888;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 8px;
    font: var(--font-open_sans);
    font-weight: 400;
}

.inputLabel {
    color: #888;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    font: var(--font-open_sans);
    font-weight: 400;
}

.inputContainer {
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.countryCode {
    flex: 0 0 30%;
    padding: 14px 12px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(234, 100, 217, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 4px rgba(234, 100, 217, 0.1);
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 8px 0 0 8px;
    background-color: #F8F8F8;
    font-family: var(--font-open_sans);
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #333;
    outline: none;
}

.phoneNumber {
    flex: 1;
    padding: 14px 12px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(234, 100, 217, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 4px rgba(234, 100, 217, 0.1);
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0 8px 8px 0;
    background-color: #F8F8F8;
    font-family: var(--font-open_sans);
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #333;
    outline: none;
}

.signInButton {
    background-color: #d3d3d3;
    padding: 10px 0;
    font: var(--font-open_sans);
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
}

.signInButton:hover {
    background-color: #a9a9a9;
}


I
Country Code Selector: I’m using a basic  element for the country code. Is there a better way to implement this, especially considering accessibility and user experience?
